# If-else statement for a string

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a conditional statement such that if the conditions are met, then string oranges ="yes please". If not, then it should say "no, thanks". I intend to use the string oranges later on in a print statement like System.out.println("y"+ "m" + "d" + "oranges"). y, m and d are user inputs. Here's the relevant part of my code. What am I doing wrong?

(Experience level: just started out with Java a few days ago)

```
String oranges;
      if ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)){
        String oranges = "yes please";
      }
        else
        {String oranges = "no, thanks";
        }
```

Comment: The line `String oranges;` declares a variable named `oranges`, and the line `String oranges = "yes please";` declares *another* variable that is *also* named `oranges`. If you want the second statement to *assign* the first variable instead, it ought to be `oranges = "yes please";`.

Comment: You can print like this  `System.out.format("%d %d %d %s", y, m,d, oranges );`. Besides that, don't declare oranges multiple times so remove oranges declaration from if-else condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the redeclaring the datatype of orange, the first declarations is fine then the second issue is your output should not have oranges in quotes as that will not output the value of oranges variable. Putting quotes will result in oranges being outputted as a string.

Here is an example of what I just explained

```js
public class JavaApplication1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String oranges = "Any thing you want";
      int y = 0;
      int m = 0;
      int d = 0;

      if ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)){
        oranges = "yes please";
      }
      else{
        oranges = "no, thanks";
        }
     System.out.println(y+ m + d + oranges);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: the code is fine it should run fine without afterToday

Comment: copy and run it in your IDE you will see its fine

Comment: `String oranges = "Any thing you want";
      int y = 0;
      int m = 0;
      int d = 0;

      if ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)){
        oranges = "yes please";
      }
      else{
        oranges = "no, thanks";
        }
String a = oranges;
     System.out.println(y+ m + d + a); `

Comment: The string at the end is the only difference I have in my code. The code compiles and runs put it doesn't follow the condition properly, gives me no thanks every time, regardless of whether or not the condition is satisfied

Comment: Remember the && operator is only true if all conditions are true meaning y>2777 and m>2 and d>22 for you to get yes please. Try these values and see the output y = 8888; m = 7770; d = 7870;

Comment: awesome happy Java coding, and remember to like the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also go the cool route and try a ternary operator approach

```
 String oranges = ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)) ? "yes please" : "no, thanks";
```

syntax is ?=then, : = else

In this approach you only need one string variable.

Happy Java Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your code can not complie successfully, you have declared `oranges` twice. Take a look at global variable and local variable. The right should be this:

```
String oranges;
if ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)){
    oranges = "yes please";
}
else{
    oranges = "no, thanks";
}
System.out.println(oranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
  String oranges,afterToday;

  int x, y , d; //here code goes to get user input 

  if ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)){
      oranges = "yes please";
  }else{
       afterToday = "no, thanks";
  }
  System.out.println("Y = "+y "M = "+m + "D ="+d + "Oranges: "+oranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your code as

```
String oranges="";
 //declare y,m and d and initialize with some value or read data from user
 //int y,d,m;
  if ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)){
    oranges = "yes please";
  }
    else
    {
      oranges = "no, thanks";
    }
System.out.println(y+" "+m+" "+d+" "+oranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which you can use to achieve your objective and includes the `System.out.printf(String, Object...)` method for printing (this method provides a lot more control over output format than `System.out.println(String)` alone; `printf` documentation can be seen [h̲e̲r̲e̲](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))):

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Code in which the variables y, m, and d are created and assigned proper values goes here.

        String oranges = ((y > 2777) && (m > 2) && (d > 22)) ? "yes please" : "no, thanks";
        System.out.printf("%d %d %d %s", y, m, d, oranges);
    }
}
```